# Proper handling of chuncked Http Response within Socket

Tags: java, sockets, webservice-client

I have some major problem detecting the true end of a http response within Socket (I have to use sockets as it was requested). We're communicating with a webservice that sends chuncked responses. I have no problems reading a response if it returns in one piece. However when it's being split all hell breaks loose :).
For example:

```
UserA -> RequestA -> Response[1] -> Processed
UserA -> RequestA -> Response[1] -> Processed
UserB -> RequestB -> a)Response[0,1] -> Processed[a.0]
UserB -> RequestB -> b)Response[0,1] -> Processed[a.1] <- From the previous line. And thus the true response to request B have to be processed again.
```

What is the preferred way to handle this kind of situation? Btw, the WS also returns the Content-Length header attribute, but honestly I have a head-ache from handling that. For that it seems like I have to read the headers fields to a ByteArrayOutputStream and check if it contains the Content-Length information. Then retrieve the actual length and wait until the is.available() reaches this value. Since the available method returns an estimation I do not trust it. So what would be the proper way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer should be:

```
private static byte[] convert(final InputStream is) throws IOException {
    final byte[] END_SIG = new byte[]{"\r".getBytes()[0], "\n".getBytes()[0]};
    final List<Byte> streamBytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();
    int readByte;
    byte[] bytes;

    // Read HTTP header:
    while ((readByte = is.read()) != -1) {
        streamBytes.add((byte) readByte);
        if (streamBytes.size() > 4) {
            int sbsize = streamBytes.size();

            int rp = sbsize - 4;
            int np = sbsize - 2;
            int rn = sbsize - 3;
            int nn = sbsize - 1;

            if (END_SIG[0] == streamBytes.get(rp) && END_SIG[0] == streamBytes.get(np) && END_SIG[1] == streamBytes.get(rn) && END_SIG[1] == streamBytes.get(nn)) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Convert to byte[]
    bytes = new byte[streamBytes.size()];
    for (int i = 0, iMAX = bytes.length; i < iMAX; ++i) {
        bytes[i] = streamBytes.get(i);
    }

    // drop header
    streamBytes.clear();

    // Convert byte[] to String & retrieve the content-length:
    final String HEADER = new String(bytes);
    int startIndex = HEADER.indexOf("Content-Length:") + "Content-Length:".length() + 1;
    int length = 0;
    int I = startIndex;
    while (Character.isDigit(HEADER.charAt(I++))) {
        ++length;
    }
    final String CL = HEADER.substring(startIndex, startIndex + length);

    // Determine the number of bytes to read from now on:
    int ContentLength = Integer.parseInt(CL);
    while (streamBytes.size() < ContentLength) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];

        int rc = is.read(buffer);
        for (int irc = 0; irc < rc; ++irc) {
            streamBytes.add(buffer[irc]);
        }
    }

    // Convert to byte[]
    bytes = new byte[streamBytes.size()];
    for (int i = 0, iMAX = bytes.length; i < iMAX; ++i) {
        bytes[i] = streamBytes.get(i);
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

And in one place this is the answer to a question.

Comment: `int startIndex = HEADER.indexOf(...)+...` -- _indexOf()_ may return -1, it is possible that `Content-Length` is not there.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way is to use existing code that already handles it: for example, HttpURLConnection or the Apache HTTP Client. There's no good reason for you to be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: This would be an answer to a totally different question but thanks! The question clearly stated: As requested, Sockets must be used. Which obviously means that HttpURLConnection or Apache HTTPClient is waaaaay out of ideas. But thanks!

Comment: This is the answer to the question unless you can give a convincing  reason why these suggestions are out of scope. The only one I would accept is an examination requirement. If it was a client specification I would talk him out of it on cost grounds.

Comment: HttpURLConnection still gives me an InputStream that I have to read. So what would be the benefit of using it? Same goes for Apache Http Client. So why would I use any of them? Non-JDK components cannot be used in the current environment. Now that leaves me two options. Either HttpUrlConnection and who cares about clearly given tasks, or go by Sockets are they were requested. I've chosen to go by request and clearly asked: How to read the InputStream. You didn't give an answer to this question.